# How can I disable INFO jaeger logging entries, in a tornado integration?

Tags: python, tornado, jaeger

I have a tornado application in which I use jaeger for tracing.

```
jaeger-client==4.3.0
tornado==6.0.4
```

My problem is that jaeger keeps logging at the INFO level, tons of entries like this :

```
INFO [jaeger_tracing:73]: Reporting span ...
```

I've tried a bunch of configuration to try to remove these entries, but so far without luck.

My current jaeger logger configurations is:

```
[logger_jaeger]
level = ERROR
qualname = jaeger_tracing
handlers = console
```

How can I turn off, INFO logging for jaeger ?

Answer (score 1):

> logging.getLogger("jaeger_tracing").setLevel(logging.WARNING)

or

> logging.getLogger("jaeger_tracing").disabled = True